# regain constant pseudo-random in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, random

I am including the same "random.inc" in foo.php and bar.php. For each, I want reproducible "random" results.

So in foo.php I always want one set of numbers and/or keywords. In bar.php another. Which shouldn't change on reload. That's what I mean by **contant** pseudo-random. And that's why I seeding on the url. However I still get different results for individual numbers as well as for array pickson every reload. This is the full php file:

```
<?
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $seed = crc32( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    echo "phpversion: ".phpversion()."\nseed: $seed\n";
    srand( $seed ); // (seed verified to be contant as expected)

    // neither single values nor array pics turn out deterministic
    echo ''.rand(0,100).' '.rand(0,100).' '.rand(0,100)."\n";
    $values = array( '0'=>21,'1'=>89,'2'=>96,'3'=>47,'4'=>88 );
    print_r( array_rand( $values, 3 ) );
?>
```

In the days of PHP4.1 it was (verified) possible to achieve constant pseudo-random like this. [array_rand API documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) describes as a feature that since 4.2 initialization happens automatically. Perhaps this is overriding any explicit seeding? (if so, perhaps explicit seeding should raise an internal PHP flag, preventing automatic seeding?). Btw: mt_srand() and srand() are equally not working.

I would really like to get my *deterministic* / *constant* pseudo-random back...

**Update:** Solution below (Windows and/or version 5.2 's fault)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the random function here?

Comment: `array_rand()` still responds to a preset `srand()` for me. PHP5.3.3/amd64

Comment: (There is only pseudo-random. There is no such thing as random.)

Comment: @mario @Fronker For me too. (PHP 5.3.0/Win32) **edit** [Wanna bet the result is `int(3)`](http://ideone.com/q7iTK)?

Comment: @all: I clarified above example with full source. And again verified it doesn't work under 5.2.17 (hoster's choice, no influence).  Do those (4+3 lines combined) really work for you ???

Comment: @Rudie: yeah I know, _pseudo_ is misleading, _constant_ is the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys, you are all correct! (Sorry, I answer it myself now)

- my web hoster runs 5.2.17 under Linux 2.6.36, and above problem exists.
- under Win x64 5.3.0 everything works as expected.

So it's everyone's guess if that's an OS related bug and/or a PHP bug, fixed in 5.3.0.

Given that random constant seeding worked before, I am guessing they fixed in 5.3 the bug that came with the autoseed feature enhancement in 4.2. Anyway, Thanx again, at least there's clarity now.

Comment: `array_rand()` has a lot of bugs :(

Answer (score 3):

Works for me (PHP/5.3.6):

```
<?php

$data = range(1, 100);
srand(1);
print_r(array_rand($data, 3));
```

... always prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] => 89
    [2] => 95
)
```

... in my machine. Apparently, the [exact numbers differ](http://3v4l.org/uv4Jf) depending on the exact environment but they're [reproducible](http://3v4l.org/An2Uf).

Comment: Thanx. And you're totally right, the issue seems to be only <PHP 5.3 and on Linux only. (below)

Comment: I think it is just PHP 5.2 on *nix (not all PHP < 5.3)

Comment: But it does not seem to work for ```array_rand($data, 100)``` why is that?

Comment: it is not getting shuffled, if the length of the range is "too close" ```array_rand```'s ```$num``` param. What you have shared works as expected but if I change the ```$num```(which is 3 in your example) param to ```100```, it is not being shuffled. Instead it's just a linear array.

Comment: @beku8 - This question is about getting reproducible sequences of pseudo-random numbers. You've found an issue with `array_rand()` (a real pain I've myself grumbled about) but, unless I'm missing something, it's unrelated to either the question or my answer.

Comment: I just wanted to shuffle my array but keep the order same all times, but this method is probably not suited. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The seeding functions are still available, and should still work; it's just since PHP 4.2 they are automatically seeded with the time on page load; but you can still call them to reset the random sequence to a known starting point.

[edit] I have just done a quick test program to make sure I wasn't imagining it!

```
mt_srand(50000);
print "rand="+mt_rand(0,10000);
```

Using PHP 5.2, this always results in the same value being printed (1749).

[EDIT]
As noted by @cwd and in the accepted answer to this question, there appears to be a discrepancy in PHP 5.2's behaviour with random number seeding between the Linux and Windows versions. In PHP 5.2 on Linux, the above technique does not appear to work.

Fortunately, the bug seems to have been fixed in PHP 5.3, so the solution to this problem is simply to upgrade. (PHP 5.2 is not supported any longer, so you should upgrade anyway)

Comment: Thanx. But I am guessing you are on windows or 5.3 ? (see below)

Comment: i can confirm this does not work in php 5.2.17 on linux - different random values on each run.

Comment: @CWD - While you may be able to confirm that it doesn't work, I can confirm that it does. I tested this on PHP 5.2 on Windows, and it worked as expected. But if you read the accepted answer, you'll see that it is likely a bug specific to PHP 5.2 on Linux. I guess the real solution is to upgrade to PHP 5.3 -- 5.2 is getting pretty ancient now.

Comment: i believe your answer should specify that you are using windows, it is inaccurate to say "Using PHP 5.2, this always results in the same value being printed" - that is not true.

Comment: @cwd -- I didn't know that at the time. By the time I found out, the OP had posted the answer for himself and accepted it, so I didn't bother to update the answer. However, I'll update it now for you.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, if anyone else wants "constant windows-pre-5.3 pseudo-random" (of low quality, e.g. for stuff like SEO buzzwording) this is a tested workaround:

```
$r = abs(crc32($URL))%20; // a number between 0 and 19, based on URL
```

Comment: that's fine but what if you need a sequence?

Comment: @cwd: for( $i=0;i<10;i++)  print abs(crc32($URL+i))%20;   Yes, dirty. And certainly low quality random. But for just a bit of shuffling it should suffice. (Having said that, crc32 should basically have a good 'random distribution', where similar input does not lead to similar results. So maybe it's even high quality 'pseudo random'...

Comment: For an extremely high quality random number, use this: `abs(crc32(sha1($URL))) % 20`. I tested a million random numbers between 0 - 50 and they're just about perfectly distributed – perhaps you'd like to edit your answer to use that.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.2.17 and probably on all versions of PHP 5.2, (not sure about windows), we lose the capability of generating random numbers based on a seed as PHP changes the algorithm used for random numbers.

rand and mt_rand are "broken" not only because they will not give one random number, but they will also not give a same sequence of random numbers - even when using a seed!

At first the PHP developers tried to argue that this is the way that it "should" work, but we can guess they caught enough grief about the problem that they have reverted the way that it works with PHP 5.3.

See the [php mt_rand page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) and the [bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40724) to learn about this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. In line with my experience... (also on the fix in 5.3 part)